# How do you perform Drag and Drop using Selenium on Safari for iPhone using C#?

Tags: c#, iphone, selenium, drag-and-drop

I've been going round in circles for ages and can't find an answer that works for me. Here is my situation.

1. I am using Visual Studio and C# to automate testing a web page on Safari for an iPhone
2. Actions and ITouchActions fail as it keeps giving me an error message saying Unsupported, and I've read on other sites that Actions is unsupported on iPhone. I don't know why ITouchActions fails.

I've see many people suggesting to use JavaScriptExectuor, but I cannot find a good example.
So far I can use JSE to just click on a page element, but I have no idea how to use it to drag and drop.
To click a web element I am using this, and it works.

```
IJavaScritpExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('#nextButton').click()");
```

So I've got 2 questions

1. Is JavaScriptExecutor the only way to drag and drop a web element on an iPhone?
2. If so, what is the code to do this in C#?
3. Does the JSE code only work with CSSelecetrs and not Xpath?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: On an iPhone, I've had success using the `TouchActions` class of the `Appium.Interfaces` library. For Web, I've never been able to get drag and drop working -- might be an issue with the web pages themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I believe TouchActions is only designed to work on apps, as I received the following error when I used it: 
"The Touch API is aimed for usage in NATIVE context. Consider using "execute"
 API with custom events trigger script to emulate touch events being in WEBVIEW context."
However I have found a solution using the JavaScriptExecturor which I have added as a reply to my initial question.

Comment: Ah that's a good point. I've only done app automation, not browser -- it's weird that the driver actions aren't compatible across the entire device, but I guess it makes sense. Glad you found a solution, and thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to scrolling using C#, iOS and Safar, I have posted the code below and hope that it helps anybody else running into this problem.

I create a variable "js" using the IJavaScriptExecutor interface
I create web elements to hold the element I want to drag, and the element I want to drag it to.
I then find the centre of each item and save them in some ints
I then create a dictionary which holds the individual commands for the script to follow, you can find more information about that on the Appium page [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures/index.html#mobile-scroll)

Finally I pass this dictionary and the name of the script I wish to perform to the js variable and let it execute.

```
    public bool DragAndDropJavascript(string dragElement, string dropElement)
    {
        try
        {  
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            // The element to drag
            // The element to drop on
            IWebElement dragFrom = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(dragElement));
            IWebElement dragTo = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(dropElement));

            // The top left corner of the drag element
            int fromX = dragFrom.Location.X;
            int fromY = dragFrom.Location.Y;

            // Add half the height and half the width
            // to find the centre of the drag element
            int fromCentreX = fromX + dragFrom.Size.Width / 2;
            int fromCentreY = fromY + dragFrom.Size.Height / 2;

            // The top left corner of the drop element
            int toX = dragTo.Location.X;
            int toY = dragTo.Location.Y;

            // Add half the height and half the width
            // to find the centre of the drop to element
            int toCentreX = toX + dragTo.Size.Width / 2;
            int toCentreY = toY + dragTo.Size.Height / 2;

            Dictionary<string, object> dragNDrop = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dragNDrop.Add("duration", 1.0);
            dragNDrop.Add("fromX", fromCentreX);
            dragNDrop.Add("fromY", fromCentreY + 50); // 50 compensates for Safari header
            dragNDrop.Add("toX", toCentreX);
            dragNDrop.Add("toY", toCentreY + 50);


            js.ExecuteScript("mobile:dragFromToForDuration", dragNDrop);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Appium may suggest you use their `dragAndDrop` method, but I've never had success with it -- I had to write my own custom action using `Press`, `MoveTo`, and `Release`.

The following code has worked for me with Android -- it may be worth giving it a try on iOS:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Interfaces;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.MultiTouch;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


// need to wrap this in IPerformsTouchActions driver, not regular AndroidDriver
public void DragAndDrop(this IPerformsTouchActions driver, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
{
    new TouchAction(driver).Press(startX, startY).MoveTo(endX, endY).Release().Perform();
}
```

We can call this method as such:

```
var fromElement = driver.FindElement(someLocator);
var toElement = driver.FindElement(someOtherLocator);

driver.DragAndDrop(fromElement.Coordinates.LocationOnScreen.X, fromElement.Coordinates.LocationOnScreen.Y, toElement.Coordinates.LocationOnScreen.X, toElement.Coordinates.LocationOnScreen.Y);
```

This should get you started hopefully. You can substitute `Press` with `LongPress`, or use `Press().Wait(500)` (ms). You may need to try out a few different options to get this working for your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I tried using TouchActions it gave me an error 
    "The Touch API is aimed for usage in NATIVE context. Consider using "execute"
    API with custom events trigger script to emulate touch events being in WEBVIEW 
    context."
So it appears that it only works for apps and not Safari. I did find an answer last night which I'll now post below.